# Paypal subscription and monthly payment method

Tags: php, paypal, recurring-billing

I am creating an application that provide the Hosted Service. And I have created some monthly subscription plans for it.

I am using PayPal Website Pro as a Payment Processor I am little confused what method I should use to charge the end user.

I have 2 solution in my mind.

1. I can create a recurring profile on PayPal that automatically going to charge.
2. On subscription I can save User's credit card on PayPal and then I can charge every month from stored card by implementing own logic.

I am families with solution 1, but not with the solution 2.

I am looking forward with solution 2, As user do not need to enter their credit card details again and again while upgrading the plan and if do not want to continue he/she can simply remove the card from the web site. But I do not know any drawback of using it.

Please help me to decide the method. Can I go freely with solution 2?

Thank in Advance

Answer (score 0):

If I'm a user of your service and I sign up for a subscription I don't want to ever have to re-enter my credit card information every time my subscription is due. Option #2 is the best way. Also - please make your users aware of the fact that they will be billed automatically... nothing will make people more mad than surprise charges.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I am just worry about is there any limitation with Sol#2 and is it a proper way to do it. Do other websites also follow the same like hosting company etc...

Comment: Use [recurring payment](https://www.paypal.com/pdn-recurring) from Paypal. This is most likely how businesses do it.

Comment: This is what the solution#1 is, Creating recurring profile on PayPal and charge automatically. No need to save the credit card. I am thing for Solution#2 which is: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#store-a-credit-card

Comment: And charging through this stored card every month.

Comment: If you are creating a subscription service you should use the service paypal built exactly for that. Why wouldn't you?

Comment: I want to save the credit card, So that if user want to Upgrade/Downgrade their plan he/she can use it. And if he want to close simply remove the card. no need to do anything with the subscription profile.

Comment: If user change and put the wrong Card Details on next subscription it will we will validate and notify the user.